# Upload zip file onto remote server using CURL?

Tags: php

i know that we can upload files such as .txt or images (.jpg, .png) onto a remote server using PHP curl.

and I also know that it is possible to upload other types of files onto a remote server using FTP functions in PHP.

but I was wondering if it is possible to upload zip folders/files onto a remote server using `PHP CURL` the same way that we upload image files without the use of FTP?

the code bellow will upload images onto a remote server. how can one use the same type of method to upload zip folders onto a remote server and then extract it?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding='multipart/form-data' method='post' action="form.php">
  <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" value="choose">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?
if ( isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) ) {
 $filename  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
 $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
 $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
 $POST_DATA = array(
   'file' => base64_encode($data)
 );
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://extserver.com/handle.php');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close ($curl);
 echo "<h2>File Uploaded</h2>";
}
?>


$encoded_file = $_POST['file'];
$decoded_file = base64_decode($encoded_file);
/* Now you can copy the uploaded file to your server. */
file_put_contents('subins', $decoded_file);
```

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks

Comment: curl couldn't care less what kind of file you're uploading. the receiving server, however, might.

Comment: If you want to treat ZIP files differently, then adapt your `handler.php` script to do so.

Comment: @MarcB, so basically, i can upload any type of file with my code as long as the server allows it?

Comment: @shell Exactly curl doesn't care about the filetype of the file that you're uploading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl just need the full path of the file that you wanted to upload with '@' before it.

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) ) {
    $filePath  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];

    $POST_DATA = array(
        'file' => '@'.  realpath($filePath)
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://extserver.com/handle.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close ($curl

     if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
        echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>File Uploaded</h2>";
    }
}
```

Extra :

Prefer using `<?php` instead of `<?`

If you want to check if there is any error with curl use this

```
if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this code yet but i will select it as an answer as it looks good and seems to do what I am trying to do. thumbs up.

Comment: I did try your code as is with the error reporting and it didn't work! it only uploads a file called `subins` onto the remote server with no extensions and `0 BYETS` of data in it which means its empty! any idea?